# Unable to launch a website in firefox browser using firefox Driver config

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, firefoxdriver

I am Unable to launch a website in firefox browser using firefox Driver config.
Jmeter version : 5.5
Firefox version installed on system : 110.0
. Below are the jmeter logs,

```
2023-02-16 14:55:35,984 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error calling threadStarted
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line 
Host info: host: 'KESHAVSS298-UB', ip: '192.168.2.21'
Build info: version: '4.7.2', revision: '4d4020c3b7'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_241'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: firefox, moz:debuggerAddress: true, moz:firefoxOptions: {args: [], profile: UEsDBBQACAgIAPF2UFYAAAAAAAA...}, proxy: Proxy(system)}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: firefox, moz:debuggerAddress: true, moz:firefoxOptions: {args: [], profile: UEsDBBQACAgIAPF2UFYAAAAAAAA...}, proxy: Proxy(system)}}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:148) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.7.2.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:106) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.7.2.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.7.2.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:156) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.7.2.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.7.2.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.7.2.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:535) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.7.2.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:228) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.7.2.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:156) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.7.2.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:130) ~[selenium-firefox-driver-4.7.2.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:126) ~[selenium-firefox-driver-4.7.2.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.FirefoxDriverConfig.createBrowser(FirefoxDriverConfig.java:36) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.7.2.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.FirefoxDriverConfig.createBrowser(FirefoxDriverConfig.java:15) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.7.2.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.getPreparedBrowser(WebDriverConfig.java:215) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.7.2.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.threadStarted(WebDriverConfig.java:146) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.7.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:797) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:993) ~[jorphan.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:976) ~[jorphan.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:765) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:753) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:264) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
2023-02-16 14:55:35,984 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error while processing sampler: 'jp@gc - WebDriver Sampler1'.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Browser has not been configured.  Please ensure at least 1 WebDriverConfig is created for a ThreadGroup.
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler.sample(WebDriverSampler.java:63) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.7.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:651) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:570) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
2023-02-16 14:55:35,984 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1
```

[image]

Also I have tried solutions from below link but no luck.

```
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/44197/unable-to-launch-and-set-the-geckodriver-using-firefox-driver-config?newreg=a459140114d04c5da24c0e78d35c11a6
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Firefox binary under your operating system [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))

---

If you cannot amend your PATH variable you will need to switch to the [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) with [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) and provide Firefox binary location via `moz:firefoxOptions.binary` capability or [FirefoxBinary](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxBinary.html) class